# What are these white granules at the leaf-ends of my gold fruit palm?

Tags: fertilizer, palm

I have had a gold fruit palm in my apartment for over a year now, and it has always been happy and healthy.  Recently I have begun fertilising it once a week or so with a (German) liquid palm fertiliser, carefully following the instructions.

A week or so after I started (give or take), white granules appeared at the tips of most of the leaves (see photos).  When I brush it off, it feels like salt (i.e., like tiny crystals).

Does anyone know:

1. What it is?
2. What is causing it?

Is it possible to over-fertilising a potted house palm?  Attempting to translate, the ingredients of the fertiliser are:

- 2.6% Nitrate
- 2.6% Ammonium
- 1.8% Carbamide/urea (CO(NH<sub>2</sub>)<sub>2</sub>)
- 3.0% Phosphate (P<sub>2</sub>O<sub>5</sub>)
- 5.0% K<sub>2</sub>O

[image: Close-up of two leaf tips]

[image: One side of the plant, showing more leaf tips]

Comment: It looks like mineral deposits to me. Do you mist or spray this plant with water?

Comment: No, I only water it using a watering can, pouring water directly onto the soil in the pot.